# Number base converter program not showing the answer

Tags: java, radix

This is my homework and it is due tomorrow. We have to write a program with Java on Bluej where a number has to be converted to base 10 and then another method to convert a number from base 10 to any base. The user types in the number and the base first and then they choose which method they want. I am using two classes for this program: "Runner" and "Converter". My Runner class runs the program and asks the user what to type and then it calls the method. The Converter class has the two methods with their algorithms. Runner class is below and the Convert class will be below the Runner:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Runner
 {

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Converter calc = new Converter();
    System.out.println("Enter a number ::");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a base number ::");
    int base = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Press 1 to convert TO base 10.");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to convert FROM base 10.");
    int calculationKey = scan.nextInt();

    if (calculationKey == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(calc.convertToTen(number, base));
    }
    else if(calculationKey == 2)
    {
        System.out.println(calc.convertToBase(number, base));
    }

    else         
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }


  }
}
```

Converter class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class Converter
 {

    private int remainder, exponent, length, answer;

 public int convertToTen(int number, int base)
  {
    int num1 = number;

    length=0;
    while(number > 0 )
    {
        num1 = num1 / 10;
        length++;
    }
    int length2 = length;
    for (exponent = 0; exponent  <= length2; exponent++)
    {


        remainder = number % 10;
        answer = (remainder * (base ^ exponent));
        answer++;

    }

    return(answer); 
  }

  public int convertToBase(int number, int base)
  { 
    int num1 = number;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        number = number % base;

    }
    return remainder;

  }

}
```

Comment: Try to print `calculationKey` before the if statements and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: @cricket_007 The calculationKey variable was already before the if statements.

Comment: I said print it. Are you sure you are entering the if statements?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes the if statements are there. They are not commented out, and my program was always like this.

Comment: Okay... So something should be printing... What exactly is the problem with this code?